# Error trying to save image

Tags: java, android, image, save

Whenever i run this app on my nexus 7 it will allow me to take an image however when i accept the image it says "there was a problem saving your photo or image". I believe it is because my device has no external storage, how would i modify this code to allow it to save on the internal storage in its own folder and afterwards display the image on an image view for editing.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CameraButton);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image_view);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
            public void  onClick(View v) {
        Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = getfile();
                camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

private File getfile()
{

    File folder = new File("=sdcard/Camera_App");

    if(!folder.exists()) //CHECKS FOR FOLDER
    {
        folder.mkdir();  //IF NO FOLDER IT CREATES FOLDER
    }

    File image_file = new File(folder, "Image.jpg");
    return image_file;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String path = "sdcard/Camera_App/Image.jpg";
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));

}


}
```

Comment: 02-07 17:19:17.037  10173-10173/aaronmiller.comp4_project E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/Camera_App/Image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe it is because my device has no external storage

That would be rather surprising. Every device that legitimately has the Play Store on it ships with [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> how would i modify this code to allow it to save on the internal storage in its own folder

That is unlikely to be practical. Other apps do not have access to your app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). You could try writing a `ContentProvider` that offers write access to a stream, backed by a file on internal storage, but I suspect that many camera apps will not know what to do with a `content://` `Uri` passed in as `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Moreover, your problem is far more likely to be your hardcoded paths. You have two such paths. Neither are the same, and neither are correct. Use methods [like `getExternalFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) (available on `Context` and subclasses like `Activity`), or `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, to get at root directories for storage, then use `File` constructors to refer to contents of those directories.

For example, this activity takes a picture, then launches a third-party image viewer to show the results:

```
package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import java.io.File;

public class CameraContentDemoActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File dir=
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    output=new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));

    startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(output), "image/jpeg");
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(That activity really needs to save the `File` in the `onSaveInstanceState()` `Bundle`, in case our app's process terminates while the camera app is in the foreground. I will update [the sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) eventually to fix that.)

With regards to populating an `ImageView`, I suspect that `createFromPath()` will do disk I/O and image decoding on the main application thread, which will freeze your UI while that is going on. There are [many image-loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that can take your `File` or `Uri` and populate your `ImageView` asynchronously.

Comment: How would i modify the sample code you supplied to instead open the image inside my image view instead of a third party application. Sorry i am new to java. also in the code you supplied what makes the application open the camera when launched, how would i also modify it to open the camera when a button is pressed.

Comment: I have implemented a button however i am still unsure how to open the image in an image view instead of a 3rd party app